# why my query getting records which are not matching in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following query

```
select user_address from  `user_data`  where  survey_id = '0005CA8A915C' limit 1;
```

and the output is:

[image]

how is that possible 5 is equal to `'0005CA8A915C'`?
means 5 = `'0005CA8A915C'` ?

---

DB structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ........
  `survey_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
 ........
  KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3509593 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `survey_id` column?

Comment: And why the `php` tag? What difference does that make to this question?

Comment: survey_id is  bigint 20

Comment: Curious why you're searching for '0005CA8A915C' in a column known to only contain integers....

Comment: its a user input field i made the example buddy

Comment: You should be validating all user inputs for the correct types, then you wouldn't need to worry about this.

Comment: Why are you comparing an int with a string?
set both of them to be the same type and validate your post!

Comment: ok guys ok but what is the solution here,  where  survey_id = CAST('0005CA8A915C' AS char)  it do the same

Comment: Since the column is an integer, then string gets converted to an integer on comparison. `0005CA8A915C` becomes `0005` since right after that is the first letter, which then becomes `5`. Try casting the column to a char/varchar, not the value you're trying to compare. Or validate that the value being passed is an integer before passing it into your query.

Comment: Your survey_id field should be varchar